# Error in showing 3 parts in one single view in android tablet

Tags: android

My application for android tablet contains 3 parts in one single view.

1. Listview items
2. On Click of list that contained in first part the second list items is shown in second part.
3. On Click of list that contained in second part the detils of each list should be shown in third part.

I have tried this but it crashes.Can Any anyone help me.

//PlaceDemo

```
package com.places.android;

public class PlaceDemo extends Activity 
{
private InputStream is;

private ListView lister2;
private ListView lister1;

private List<PlaceType> m_Placetypelist;

protected PlaceAdapter pladapter;

private static Place m_CurrentPlace;

public static Place getCurrentPlace ()
{
    return m_CurrentPlace;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.place);

    try 
    {
         is = getAssets().open("place_file.json");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
         Gson gson = new Gson();

         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

         Places response = gson.fromJson(reader,Places.class);

         m_Placetypelist = response.plist;
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lister1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);

    PlaceTypeAdapter ptadapter = new PlaceTypeAdapter(this, R.layout.row, R.id.text, m_Placetypelist);
    lister1.setAdapter(ptadapter );

    lister1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) 
        {
            pladapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceDemo.this,  R.layout.row, R.id.text, m_Placetypelist.get(position).place);

            lister2.setAdapter(pladapter );

            pladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    lister2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView2);

    lister2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) 
        {
            m_CurrentPlace = pladapter.getItem(position);

            PlaceDetails details = (PlaceDetails) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.placedetail_frag);

            PlaceDetails det =  new PlaceDetails(m_CurrentPlace);

            FragmentManager fragMgr = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.placedetail_frag , det);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

            ft.commit();

        }
    });
}

//Adapters

public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Place>
{

    public PlaceAdapter(Context context,  int resource, int txtviewresourceid, List <Place> items) 
    {
        super (context, resource, txtviewresourceid, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

      View v = view;

        if (v == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        Place _p = this.getItem(position);
        id.setText(_p.name);

        return v;
    }

}

public class PlaceTypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <PlaceType> 
{

    public PlaceTypeAdapter(Context context, int resource, int txtviewresourceid, List<PlaceType> objects) 
    {
        super (context, resource, txtviewresourceid, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

      View v = view; 

        if (v == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        PlaceType _pt = this.getItem (position);
        id.setText(_pt.name);

        return v;
    }

}
}

 **place.xml**
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView1" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="#fff"  android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 

    <View  android:layout_width="2.0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#2861ad"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView2"   android:background="@color/lightgray" android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <View  android:layout_width="2.0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#2861ad"/>

        <fragment
        class="com.places.android.PlaceDetails"
        android:id="@+id/placedetail_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//PlaceDetails

```
public class PlaceDetails extends Fragment
{
private Place m_Place;

private static String lng;
private static String lat;

private Button showRouteButton;

private String desc ;

private String name;

private String link;

 public PlaceDetails(Place m_CurrentPlace) 
 {
    m_Place = m_CurrentPlace;
 }

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        desc = m_Place.desc;
        lat = m_Place.lat;
        lng = m_Place.lng;
        name = m_Place.name;
        link = m_Place.link;
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, null);

        ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(desc);
        ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lat)).setText(lat);
        ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lng)).setText(lng);
        ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);

        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.link1_view)).setText(link);

        showRouteButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.show_route);

        showRouteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                /*Intent intent=new Intent(PlaceDetails.this,PlaceMap.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putString("newlat", lat);
                b.putString("newlng", lng);

                System.out.println(lat);
                System.out.println(lng);

                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent); */

            }
        }); 

        return v;
}

}
```

**details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">   

    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="2.0">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Name" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff" 
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name" 
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minWidth="250dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:capitalize="none"/>

        <TextView  
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Description" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Latitude" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff" 
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/lat"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minWidth="250dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:capitalize="none"
             />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Longitude" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff" 
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/lng" 
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minWidth="250dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:capitalize="none"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link1_lbl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="For More Details Log On To :"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
            android:clickable="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link1_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" 
            android:paddingTop="20dip">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/show_route"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Show Map"/>

         </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Error**

```
11-28 07:25:28.160: D/dalvikvm(14331): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 4% free 6382K/6595K, paused 31ms
11-28 07:25:28.160: I/dalvikvm-heap(14331): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.785MB for 513744-byte allocation
11-28 07:25:28.230: D/dalvikvm(14331): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 6884K/7111K, paused 2ms+2ms
11-28 07:25:28.240: D/dalvikvm(14331): newInstance failed: no <init>()
11-28 07:25:28.240: D/AndroidRuntime(14331): Shutting down VM
11-28 07:25:28.240: W/dalvikvm(14331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40113760)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.places.android/com.places.android.PlaceDemo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.places.android.PlaceDemo.onCreate(PlaceDemo.java:50)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    ... 11 more
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.places.android.PlaceDetails: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:535)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4168)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    ... 22 more
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.places.android.PlaceDetails
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
11-28 07:25:28.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    ... 25 more
```